# Microsoft bot - Why does some bot example disable warning 1998

Tags: warnings, botframework

I am new in Microsoft bot development, so I started to use the examples published on Github by the company.
I noticed that some example has disabled a warning in the dialog classes:

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
```

if I remove the line, I got the expected message "The async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously..." Thats normal since the examples usually contains method calls such as  `context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);` where MessageReceivedAsync() is an async method.

I learnt that suppressing warnings is not a good approach and to resolve the cause of the warning would be the preferable. I have the feeling I miss the point here somehow. I would like to understand the concept why did the developer choose to use disable the warning here and not find another way of implementation instead? Should I do the same if I develop similar applications?

Example: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/capability-SimpleTaskAutomation/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning has been put due to the fact that a warning will be thrown by this method in your sample:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

As you can see this method is `async` but there is no awaited call inside, hence the warning.

The problem when you try to fix this one is the fact that this `StartAsync` is the implementation of the `IDialog` interface of the Bot Framework, which is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/IDialog.cs#L54):

```
public interface IDialog<out TResult>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The start of the code that represents the conversational dialog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The dialog context.</param>
    /// <returns>A task that represents the dialog start.</returns>
    Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context);
}
```

As you can see the `StartAsync` method is declared for asynchronous behavior.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification, it helped! (Btw, now that I understood this, I modified the MessageReceivedAsync() method so it has an await call inside. This way, disabling the warning is not needed anymore.)